# ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 Application can not access path on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, path, asp.net-core-mvc, systemctl

When I start the project by `dotnet run` after going in to .sln directory, this function works correctly. If I go to the `projectfolder/../bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish` and run with `dotnet project.dll` it still works correctly, but if I start this app as a service, this function does not work and catch writes this line:

> Access to the path '/home/.../projectfolder/uploaded-images/3713579a-5b47-48f7-8666-9e0b3ded3bb1.jpg' is denied.`

```cs
private async Task<FileSaveResult> SaveImage(IFormFile imageFile)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(IMAGEUPLOADPATH))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(IMAGEUPLOADPATH);
    }
    string postedFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName);
    string newName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + postedFileExtension;
    string newPath = Path.Combine(IMAGEUPLOADPATH, newName);
    try
    {
        using var fileStream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create);
        await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        return new FileSaveResult
        {
            ContentType = imageFile.ContentType,
            PhysicalAddress = newPath,
            IsSuccess = true
        };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return new FileSaveResult();
    }
}
```

This is where I initiliaze `IMAGEUPLOADPATH`

```cs
public AdminController(..., IWebHostEnvironment environment,...)
{
    ...
    VIDEOUPLOADPATH = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "uploaded-videos");
    IMAGEUPLOADPATH = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "uploaded-images");
    ...
}
```

I start service with this command
`sudo systemctl start myprojectname.service`

and this is the content of `myprojectname.service` file (I generally don't know the meanings of these lines).

```
[Unit]
Description=.....

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/..../myproject
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/.../myproject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/project.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
ProtectHome=off
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=myproject
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WntedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I solve this problem? I am starting this project via a ssh connection. I can't close the command line because it kills the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

`uploaded-videos` and `uploaded-images` folders need more permissions. NGINX cant access those folders. But when we start it with  `sudo dotnet` or `dotnet` in my case, it works with root permissions.

### Checking if this is the problem we face

1. Change directory to the project folder that contains the folders we cant access.

   `cd .../.../projectfolder`
2. List folder contents with `-l` parameter. `-l` is added to see long listing. I add `| grep uploaded-` to see contents only starting with `uploaded-`

   `ls -l - grep | uploaded-`

   `ls -l` to see all

   which prints something like this

#### Output

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 27 16:01 uploaded-images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 27 15:04 uploaded-videos
```

As we can see, both folder have permissions of `drwxr-xr-x`

`r-x` means it has permission to read and execute, but not write.

## The Solution

While you are still in the project folder. Run these commands to add write permissions to folders you want. In my case it looks something like this.

```
sudo chmod a+rwx uploaded-videos/
sudo chmod a+rwx uploaded-images/
```

### Testing the solution

Lets try to run this command again

`ls -l`

#### Output

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Nov 27 16:01 uploaded-images
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Nov 27 15:04 uploaded-videos
```

Now we have  `rwx` instead of `r-x`. So we have given write permissions successfully.

And I have tested the application, it works properly.

I did not have to restart any services after these changes.